# Would like to stack multiple rows of data to single lines

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Giving a really simplified example I have a datasheet that looks a little bit like this:

[image]

Currently each order has the information on the order, name of customer and address on the main line. But the item and price are on lines below it. What I would like is a way to move the data in the lines at the bottom to fit in with the main line, and where there is an order with more than one item, to have the catering number, name and address copied to accommodate the extra line. So, something like this:

[image]

I am wondering if there's a macro or formula that can help with this.

The actual file I have contains a lot more data and so a copy and paste job would not be efficient at all.

Comment: Using [PowerQuery](https://i.imgur.com/OZ3ZaNK.gif) is the simplest method to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 3):

```
=LET(a,A1:F8,
     b,TOCOL(ROW(a)/(TAKE(a,,-1)<>""),2),
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(b),COLUMNS(a),
   LAMBDA(x,y,
          LET(z,INDEX(a,SEQUENCE(INDEX(b,x,1)),y),
XLOOKUP(1,N(z<>""),z,,,-1)))))
```

We declare `a` the input range and `b` the last column row numbers containing data.

Then we use MAKEARRAY to lookup the last non blank cell in the current column up to current row.

Comment: I have attempted using the formula. Unfortunately whilst the first and second line were correct, the third row was this "pepsi 99 #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A"

Comment: Gotcha, that made me update my answer completely